# How to use multi account on git?

Tags: git, source-control-explorer

I have some accounts for source control, such as: *gitLab* and *Microsoft git* on my computer.

How to use my gitLab account to: init, commit, push, pull but don't sign in again?

P.S.: I use macOS and command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## How to do this

Using key based authentication will allow you to avoid having to repeat login details for every service

## How to setup keys on GitLab

The tutorial is available [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html), but the steps are:

- Generate a new key
- Add it to GitLab
- Login with the new key

Unfortunately I have not used *Microsoft git* before, so I am not able to say how you would add a key to its server.